# Should we prefer tests at a higher level of integration, or at a lower level of integration?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-tests

When talking about integration level of automated tests, I suppose that end-to-end tests lie at the first extreme: they know absolutely nothing about the internals of the app they test, they just run the app and see if it behaves as expected. On the other extreme, unit tests in the classical sense lie: they test only a single method, and all dependencies of the class they test are mocked. The mocking is done both out of perfmormance concerns, as well as in an effort to keep the test focused: the hope is that if a unit test fails, it must be immediately obvious where the error lies.

It is clear that certain things are only possible or practical to test with either unit or integration tests. However, many times the choice is not that clear-cut. A single well-written integration test can often cover more than multiple focused unit tests could cover. Question arises if, given choice, we should lean towards unit tests or integration tests.

The classical approach is summarized by the famed 'test pyramid'. It dictates that first and foremost we should strive to cover our entire codebase with unit tests. This won't test everything, in particular this won't test interactions between various classes (because of the mocking), so on top of unit tests some integration tests should be added; but these should be less numerous than unit tests and should be added after unit tests. Finally some end-to-end tests, a single end-to-end test per business requirement should be written, however these are not a responsibility of the developers, but rather of a dedicated QA team.

I've always found this approach very counter-intuitive. Adding a unit test per every single method we have, adding a mock per every single class we have incurs tremendous developer overhead. TDD proponents shoot back by claiming that chasing endless bugs will, in the end, incur even greater overhead, make developers spend 90% of their time on fixing bugs while introducing other bugs and annoy end users out of using our broken app. But I can't see how, in many cases, can unit tests help prevent bugs.

The primary goal of automated testing, as I understand it, is to forestall regressions. Therefore, unit tests are supposed to facilitate fearless refactoring and adaptation of code to changed business requirements, with the general idea being that code uncovered by unit test cannot be refactored without risking breaking it, so such code has a tendency to solidify. I cannot see how unit tests can achieve this. Assume that we have a *unit* of code and a unit test that tests this unit. Now this unit changes, either because of refactoring or because of changed business requirements. Can our unit test catch a possible regression? No, because as our unit of code changes, so our test must also be rewritten to mirror this change. Maybe even our unit of code is removed at all, in that case our unit test is also deleted. So maybe our unit test can catch regressions in other units of code? No again, because everything is mocked.

In addition, many bugs, in practice, appear not because there is an error in a particular method, but rather because developers forget about assumptions made in other pieces of code or misunderstand 3rd party APIs. Unit tests can never catch such errors.

I shared these worries with some other developers. To my surprise they agreed with me. They said that, for these reasons, unit testing is often useless. They stressed that tests should test how code behaves, what it does, while unit tests instead test how it is implemented, which is often counter-productive. They said that, contrary to the oft-cited pyramid of tests, we should strive to write tests at a higher level of integration if possible/practical, only dropping to unit tests if necessary. They felt that, contrary to a 'testable' architecture forced by covering everything with unit tests (that is supposed to also be better for this reason), a proper architecture is one that rigorously separates the 'border's of the application (everything that must deal with the database, network, in general have any side effects) and the 'core' of the application, that will contain all business logic and be written in terms of pure functions, in accordance with the functional programming paradigm. We should strive to move as much code into 'core' and have 'border's only contain as much code as absolutely necessary. Now 'core' will, indeed, have most functions covered by tests that simply call that function with a given input and test if its output is according to expectations. No mocks are needed and no other parts of code may break because of the lack of side effects. Borders, however, will, ideally, be tested purely by integration tests that don't even mock 3rd party dependencies, to guard against our misunderstandings of these 3rd party APIs. These tests will test the behavior of the application as if it was deployed. Note many applications will have very little logic, because their sole purpose is to interact with the user, the db, 3rd party APIs, etc (eg CRUDs); such applications should, in general, only have a single test per business requirement. In any case, mocks should be avoided if at all possible, only to be employed if there is no other choice. I also got linked to this article: https://tyrrrz.me/blog/unit-testing-is-overrated . They summarized their advice by the sentence: 'Stop worrying about *unit* tests; start writing good *automated* tests'.

This approach seemed to make sense to me, so I started sharing it with others. Again to my surprise I met strong resistance to this mindset. According to them all I said is why unit tests on their own are not sufficient and we must also have integration tests; however this does not, in any way, remove the need for unit tests. I was, again, told that whenever I write any piece of code it is absolutely necessary to have it 100% covered by *unit* tests, only later adding integration tests as necessary. Preferbly I should practice TDD in classical sense, that is, lock myself in 30sec-long cycles when I first write the tiniest *unit* test that fails, then write the tiniest bit of producition code that suffices to pass this test. Also, I was told, there are exponentially many pathways the execution of a code may take, so if we stick to tests at a higher level of integration, we can only get enough confidence at our code if we write exponentially as many integration tests as we would have unit tests, which is just not feasible.

Notably, in both camps, that seemed to be pretty much opposed to each other, there were programmers that seemed to be very experienced and competent.

Where is truth? Should we insist of having everything covered by unit tests that mock all dependencies, treating tests at higer levels of integration as secondary? Or should we focus on writing tests that test the behavior of the code in its entirety, only dropping to unit tests when necessary?

Also, it seems to me, that the difference between these two camps is just another example of the fundamental differences between two larger camps, that is, OO-adherents and FP-adherents. OO-adherents will love unit tests both for their own sake and because unit tests force a very specific architecture, which they believe is more OO and also preferable on its own. FP-adherents will instead want to be able to treat each funciton as a black box, without having to drop to how it is written, so they will also want to test it in the same way: by just feeding it inputs and validating its outputs, without going to its internals and mocking its parts. These parts will also be tested, but again by testing them as a whole. Also FP-adherents despise OO architecture as overly and needlessly complex, thus they also don't see such architecture, as forced by covering everything by unit tests, preferable; instead, they put forth an architecture that revolves around rigorously separating code that must have side effects and code that needs not have side effects, whith insistence that as much code as possible should not have side effects. The differences also seem philosophical. OO wants to view each unit of code as an object that talks to other objects and needs to be viewed in abstraction from these other objects, hence when looking at a particular object we will mock everything else. FP, instead, will want to be able to replace each function with the value it spits out given a particular input (referential transparency); dependencies are seen as an implementation detail that we should not be forced to look at. Is this right?